# Keep cursor from moving when yanking upwards

Tags: cursor-movement, cut-copy-paste

I frequently find myself wanting to make a copy of, eg, a function that I just wrote and modify it slightly. In such a situation, I'll generally use something like <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> to copy what I just wrote. I then have to <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> to get back to where I just was before <kbd>p</kbd>.

However, if I'm at the start of what I want to copy, <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> will not move the cursor to the end of what I just yanked, meaning that I still have to <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> before I <kbd>p</kbd>. This behavior is mentioned briefly in the help files:

> After applying the operator the cursor is mostly left at the start of
>   the text that was operated upon.  For example, "yfe" doesn't move the
>   cursor, but "yFe" moves the cursor leftwards to the "e" where the yank
>   started.

But it doesn't give a rationale for which motions move the cursor and which don't, or a way to change these behaviors.

So, long story short: how can I yank upwards (or in any particular direction) without moving the cursor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can take a different approach for this exact situation.

### Paste differently

The [`gP`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#gP) command pastes before your cursor like `P`, but leaves your cursor to the end of the pasted text instead of before.

This is effectively identical to manually restoring your cursor position before pasting with `p`.

Comment: That.... is even better. It's more succinct, and somehow feels more Vim-y. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Every command that modified the buffer (and yanks) will set the `'[` and `']` marks around the changed area. So you can go to the end of the the freshly yanked text via `']` and then do your put, `p`.

If you are just yanking line-winse then you can use the `:yank` command with a range.

```
:.-5,.yank
```

This command will yank the 5 lines above the current line to the current line. Or even shorter:

```
:-5,y
```

Details:

- Current line is represented by `.`
- `.-5` means subtract 5 from the current line
- The current line can be assumed so leave it out
- `:y` is short for `:yank`

For more help see:

```
:h :y
:h range
```

Comment: That is both good to know and an improvement, but still not ideal. What I'm really looking for is a succinct way to yank upward without having to move the cursor back to where it was.

Comment: Thanks, your edit is pretty much what I'm looking for. Your first paragraph, however, doesn't seem to work as you describe: `]` does not move to the end of what I yank.

Comment: He said `']` not `]`.